# app invitations in facebook

Tags: facebook

can we send unlimted number of app invi to users.

Can it be possible?
face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limits on the number of invites a user can send. These can be found in the applications Statistics -> Allocations page.
For one app I have I get this:

```
Integration Point           Limit   Bucket/Total    
Requests per user per day   26      9/14    
Emails per user per day    2          3/8
```

I am unaware of a possibility to "game" the limits, and I wouldn't do it anyway.